# Problema con href="#"

Tags: javascript, html5, configuración, navegador-web, href

Ya me ha pasado varias veces que al usar un href="#" (otras redirecciones href me funcionan perfectamente). Ahora mismo he copiado y modificado un código de internet. Lo he simplificado al máximo y no me funciona.

```js
songlist.onclick = function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var elm = e.target;
 var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
 var source = document.getElementById('player');
 source.src = elm.getAttribute('data-value');
 audio.load();
 audio.play();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Index</title>
 <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
 <ul id="songlist" class="songlist">
  <li>
   <a href="#" data-value="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga">Cancion</a>
  </li>  
 </ul>

 <div>
  <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
            <source id="player" src=""></source>
            - ERROR - 
  </audio>
 </div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Al ejecutarlo aquí, funciona perfectamente. Pero en local, en mi navegador, no hace nada. Supongo que es un problema de configuración, pero no sé cuál.
He usado chrome, firefox y edge y el resultado es el mismo. He probado instalando xampp como servidor local apache y nada.
En chrome, que es el que más utilizo, javascript está activado.

No sé que falla, ¿Ayuda?.
Gracias.

Comment: Vale, ya lo he resuelto.
El script hay que ejecutarlo al final.
Mea culpa.